# Scaling graphics Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio-2010, scaling

I have a problem with scaling in a program written in C # (Visual Studio 2010). Normally it should look like below (picture 1), which also works on most computers with both Windows 7 and 8. When changing the scaling via the "Make text and other items larger or smaller" in windows "Screen Resolution" to eg 125% the graphics gets screwed up on some computers but not all (see picture 2).

Each pair of circles are a "User defined control / component". These are drawn out of the body that is an image that is behind the circles. A piece of code is attached below.

```
// use high quality graphics
e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

// Set the SmoothingMode property to smooth the line.
e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

Pen pen = new Pen(_electrodeLineColor, 4 + 8 * ((float)value / MAX_ELECTRODE_VALUE));

// Set the DashCap to round.
pen.DashCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashCap.Round;

// if active then draw the line
if (_electrodeValue > 0)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, _point1, _point2);
}

// indicate hovering
Console.WriteLine("Electrode " + _electrodePairNo + ", OnPaint, hover state: " + _hover.ToString());

if (_hover)
{
    // draw selection circle 1
    e.Graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), _point1.X - _r - 3, _point1.Y - _r - 3, _diam + 5, _diam + 5);

    // draw selection circle 2
    e.Graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), _point2.X - _r - 3, _point2.Y - _r - 3, _diam + 5, _diam + 5);
}

// draw electrodes
e.Graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.LightGray), _point1.X - _r + 2, _point1.Y - _r + 2, 16, 16);
e.Graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.LightGray), _point2.X - _r + 2, _point2.Y - _r + 2, 16, 16);
```

## Picture 1

[image: http://www.inerventions.se/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/image002.png]

## Picture 2

[image: http://www.inerventions.se/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/image003.jpg]

Has someone had this problem? I am open to all sort of tips.

Regards,
Jonas

Comment: You need to include the code where _point1 and _point2 are being calculated.

Answer (score 1):

The source of your data is completely unclear but it certainly looks like it uses a unit of pixels instead of inches. Both the form and the Bitmap you use are automatically rescaled to match the DPI of the video adapter, enlarging them on a machine that is operating at 125%. You need to scale your data as well, use Graphics.DpiX/Y.  A first order estimate could look like this:

```
   var scalex = (float)e.Graphics.DpiX / image.HorizontalResolution;
   var scaley = (float)e.Graphics.DpiY / image.VerticalResolution;
   e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(scalex, scaley);
```

Where "image" is a reference to the bitmap that you draw, not otherwise visible in your snippet either.

Comment: Hi Hans Passant! I will look in to this, thanks a lot!